# Which C# type names are special?

Tags: c#

Under what inputs does [IsSpecialName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isspecialname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) return true? From my brief research I've found that property accessors and operator overloads have special names, alongside any type with a name which contains an underscore. Can anyone give me a complete description of cases in which a type name is special?

Comment: *"Can anyone give me a complete description of cases in which a type name is special"* - that's what the docs are for.

Comment: @James Except the docs are rather vague on this.

Comment: [might require special treatment by some compilers] suggest that it provides a hint to those compilers. Why would you use it?

Comment: Action selection in API routing ignores methods with special names. Plus, it's useful for reflection. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be much rigorous info on it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The CLI specification as published in ECMA-335 is a decent source for info like this.  Search the document for `rtspecialname` (names that are special to the CLR) and `specialname` (names that are special to tools.  The specialname attribute is turned on for rtspecialnames.  Giving these hits:

- The underlying `value__` field of an enumerated type
- The getter and setter accessor methods of a property
- The add, remove and fire accessors methods of an event
- Operator overloads
- The `.ctor` method of a class, the constructor
- The `.cctor` method of a class, the static constructor

Comment: What is this "fire accessor" you speak of? I can't find mention of it on MSDN.

Comment: C# doesn't allow writing that accessor.  Other languages do, like C++/CLI (raise method) and VB.NET (RaiseEvent method).

Comment: I might be completely wrong, but I think `The .ctor method of a class, the constructor` actually refers to default constructors (auto-defined by compiler) and it(def. ctor) needs to carry two flags: `MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName` & `MethodAttributes.SpecialName`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.isspecialname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

First of all IsSpecialName does not take any input. Also the property of Type is not really applicable to property accessors or operator overloads, since it's a property of a *Type* and operators/accessors are not types. This is despite what the MSDN article might tell you.

I would venture a guess that it returns true when the correspondent [TypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeattributes.aspx) is `SpecialName`. You can refer to ECMA 335 Standard to find out what is supposed to be marked as a Special Name. Incidentally, you'll learn that it's things like operators and property accessors. This explains where the confusion in the MSDN article can come from.

I believe that on `Type` this property is implemented mostly for the benefit of compilers and such that could require additional (as compared to what ECMA 335 mandate) special name handling. (Which could differ from compiler to compiler).